# FormRequest with route parameter (Laravel 5)

Tags: routes, laravel-5

I am currently looking into the FormRequest object to use it to perform authentication and validation of the incoming data. However, I cannot get it to work when using model injection.

Routes.php:

```
Route::model('post', 'Post');
Route::model('comment', 'Comment');
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
Route::resource('post.comments', 'CommentController');
```

PostRequest:

```
class StoreCommentRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function authorize()
    {
        $post = $this->route('post');
        $owners = $report->users;

        return $owners->contains(Auth::id());
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'post_id' => 'required|numeric|exists:posts,id'
        ];
    }

}
```

Whenever a Comment is posted, I get the message:

```
"The post id field is required"
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to "inject" the right value for `post_id` from the Post model that is bound to the route.

Is it possible to use route parameters? And if so, how?

Comment: inside authorize() function do `dd(\Input::all());` and check weather id value is assigned

Comment: The id parameter is not posted with the data. Instead, I would like to retrieve the parameter from the route.

Comment: try this: `$post = $this->route('post_id');` Also, `\Input::all()` should has values from route too

Comment: Is `post_id` is a URL parameter defined in a `routes.php` or is it something submitted by the form?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to validate the ID of a resource like that - you should ensure that the resource is correct at the controller level and keep the validation rules for form data. So, the handler in your controller should look like this:

```
public function store(StoreCommentRequest $request, Post $posts)
{
    $post = $posts->findOrFail($request->post_id);

    // Do some more stuff here
}
```